# HTML Error on Google Tracking Code

Tags: html, xhtml

I have developed a website and have Google tracking code added on a href around the world.

My code is xhtml validated but the tracking code is giving error. i have searched but didn't find where the problem is

```
<li><a href="index.html" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'StaticHeader', 'Home', 'Button_1']);">Home</a></li>
```

it's giving error on ( onclick="_gaq.push ) comas are highlighted

Here is the error

```
Line 86, Column 40: there is no attribute "onClick"
<a href="buy-now.html" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Home', 'B…
```

Comment: The tracking code is where the error is, not what is giving you the error. What is really telling you there is an error? A validator? A browser JS debugger? JSLint? Your IDE? What error are you getting (tell us the actual error message!)?

Comment: Make sure your 'onclick' is all lowercase. In the a tag you have it lowercase but in the error you show it's not - it's 'onClick'.

Answer (score 0):

XHTML has case [sensitive attribute and tag names](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.2). `onClick` should be `onclick`.